# Between _add_months configurastion

Tags: date, filter, formula, cognos, days

I have a report in which I'm using a filter on vehicle Wholesale date (calendar measure) trying to bring in the previous months date of transactions.

For example: Today is 8/10/23. I am wanting to see all data points that processed throughout the previous month (July 1st through July 31) (First day of month through last day of month).

I've used variations of "between (_add_days(_first_of_month(_add_months(current_date, -1))) and (_first_of_month(current_date)))" and "between _first_of_month (_add_months (current_date,-1) and _last_of_month (_add_months (current_date)".

When I use "(_first_of_month(_add_months(current_date, -1)))" only data from 7/1 show with nothing from 7/2 on. What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Based on your screen capture, maybe a basic SQL tutorial is really what you need.  And maybe a basic Cognos tutorial.  `includes` indicates you are using the GUI to produce the filter.  The quotes around your function expression indicates you want to know when the value of [Date Wholesaled] is the string you entered ('_first_of_month(_add....') in the Manually input items box on the Filter condition dialog.  Is [Date Wholesaled] a character data type?  Beyond that, please reproduce the problem using the GO Sales (query) package and post the report spec (XML) here so we have somewhere to start.

Comment: Based on the quality of this and your other questions:  StackOverflow does not exists solely to do your job for you.  It may be time for you to go get some relevant training.  IBM and other Cognos experts offer videos on YouTube.  There are several companies that offer training on IBM Cognos and other reporting tools.  And there are some good SQL tutorials online.  W3Schools has a basic tutorial, but some of their content is flawed.  MDN offers tutorials as well.  And there are other good sources of SQL training.

Answer (score 0):

> I've used variations of "between (_add_days(_first_of_month(_add_months(current_date, -1))) and (_first_of_month(current_date)))" and "between _first_of_month (_add_months (current_date,-1) and _last_of_month (_add_months (current_date)".

Ok what results did you get?  What did the generated SQL look like?  The second of your examples should work but I'm guessing what you actually did and what you say you did.

> When I use "(_first_of_month(_add_months(current_date, -1)))" only data from 7/1 show with nothing from 7/2 on. What am I missing?

What results did you get?  What did the SQL look like?  What is the complete filter expression are you using?  That, like the other two examples you used, are only fragments.

I believe you want to filter your report so that only the records to only have those for some activity between the first of the month of the previous month and the last of the month of the previous month.  Is that correct understanding?

If so create a filter similar to this.

*wholesale date* between _first_of_month ( _add_months (    current_date,-1)    ) and _last_of_month ( _add_months (    current_date,-1)    )

*wholesale date* would be the object reference (the stuff with square brackets if you are using a FM package (data module identifiers use the query subject (aka table).query item (aka column) syntax)) to the column.

The fact that you say you have tried something similar to that and it did not work (although you do not say what happened) means that you are not stating all the relevant details.

[image: data grid and metadata tree]

[image: Generated sql]

Comment: will rev the generated SQL today. The filter expression i used is exactly as written in the question. When i use ["(_first_of_month(_add_months(current_date, -1)))"], it works but again, only transactions that processed on 7/1/23 show nothing from 7/2/23-7/31/23. i used the filter you suggested and this error pops up which i've gotten before:  [XQE-V5-0011 V5 syntax error found in expression "[Date Wholesaled] in (between _first_of_month ( _add_months ( current_date,-1) ) and _last_of_month ( _add_months ( current_date,-1) ))", invalid token "between" found after "[Date Wholesaled]

Comment: When i use [(_first_of_month(_add_months(current_date, -1))) and (_last_of_month (_add_months (current_date)))] i get error stating [XQE-PLN-0268 The function '_add_months' requires 2 argument(s) in filter/slicer expression '[Date Wholesaled] in ((_first_of_month(_add_months(current_date,-1))) and (_last_of_month (_add_months (current_date))))' of query 'Query1'. to correct it, i update and add between [Between (_first_of_month(_add_months(current_date, -1))) and (_last_of_month (_add_months (current_date)))] and get the same invalid token "Between" found.

Comment: A filter expression such as this will only return the first day of the previous month.  Are you surprised to discover that?  Could you explain how you expected other results?
"(_first_of_month(_add_months(current_date, -1)))"   Also that is not the complete filter expression as it is missing the operand.  (i.e. the query item being filtered)

Comment: "[Date Wholesaled] in (between _first_of_month ( _add_months ( current_date,-1) ) and _last_of_month ( _add_months ( current_date,-1) ))", is not the expression I suggested.   You do not need the in operator.  You use the IN operator in both expressions. 

I'm assuming that Wholesaled is just a typo which you made as part of your comment.

Comment: Can you provide a picture which will aussage my fears that you are not actually in the filter UI please.

Comment: yes, initially i was surprised it was returning only the first day of month. When i don't use the AND i get an error and when i use it by itself, i get an error. really just trying to understand the correct way to add a filter where the previous months transactions show as the result output. So, in aug 23, it would display July 1-31 and when I'm in sept it would show 8/1/23-8/31/23 and so on.

Comment: Your expressions are not valid.   Use the expression I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

So, after much tinkering with the suggestions above and others, was finally able to add the filter from the Query Detail Filters (Report->Queries) as [Date Wholesaled] between _first_of_month (_add_months (current_date, -1)) and _last_of_month (_add_months (current_date, -1))

I had to add the filter using the "Detail Filter Expression" as opposed to the Filters-Query. Pics are below:

[image]
[image]